# How to create a return value using an unspecified parameter in GMOCK?

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, googlemock

Say I'm mocking class `IClass` which has a method call `RClass DoIt(int x)` like this:

```
class RClass
{
    int _x;
public:
    RClass(int x) :_x(x) { }
}

class MockClass : public IClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(DoIt, RClass(int)));
}
```

Then in my test I want to return a `RClass` value constructed with the first argument called in the code under test. I tried like this, but it didn't work:

```
int value = 0;
MockClass mc;
EXPECT_CALL(mc, DoIt(_)).WillRepeatedly(DoAll(SaveArg<0>(&value), Return(RClass(value))));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Invoke() action. It allows you to specify arbitrary behavior for a mock method. There are a number of variations, but one form will look something like this:

```
RClass fake(int x) { return RClass(x); }

ON_CALL(mc, DoIt(_))
        .WillByDefault(Invoke(&fake));
```

If you're the C++11 type, lambdas also work:

```
ON_CALL(mc, DoIt(_))
        .WillByDefault(Invoke([](int x) -> RClass { return RClass(x) }));
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I had to do and it worked fine. Cheers!